# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider in android

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, authentication

I have integrated facebook sdk for do login with Parse Api in my application but getting this problem:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider
at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:96)
at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:81)
```

I am using jars:

ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.2.jar

And Initialized facebook in application class

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

How to fix this issue please help me.

Comment: did you solved the problem, i also got similar error

Answer (score 1):

You may lose some libs. I get rid of this problem by importing these libs:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
```

in app/libs/

```
Parse-1.10.1.jar
ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.1.jar
Parse-1.10.1/
```

The folder, Parse-10.1/, is downloaded from https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing